# Regular expression to extract content from a div whose id starts with a specifc string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to extract content from a div whose id starts with a specific string, but ends with anything. Example:

I have a div

```
<div id="content_message_56384">
  My first post.
</div>
```

My code:

```
$regex = '#\<div id="content_message_[*]"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
preg_match($regex, $intro, $matches);
echo $match = $matches[0];
```

But I'm not not getting any result. Please help.

Comment: `[*]` is not the placeholder you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The code should be this:

```
$string = "<div id=\"content_message_56384\">
  My first post.
</div>";
$regex = '/<div id="content_message_(?:\d+)">(.+?)<\/div>/s';
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
print($maches[1]);
```

Please, note that I'm using a non-capturing expression here `(?:\d+)` because you only need what's inside the `<div>`.

Comment: code is working. but i need a complete div with content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$intro='<div id="content_message_56384">
  My first post.
</div><div id="content_message_5577577IIRRIR">
  My second possssss.
</div>';
$regex = '#\<div id="content_message_+.+"\>(.+?)\<\/div\>#s';
preg_match($regex, $intro, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```