# Regex parse html to display certain id tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a html which needs to be parsed that only the id that is being query needs to be displayed.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<h2 id="onlythisneedstobereturned"> hello </h2>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So if i give id as "onlythisneedstobereturned" it should return only  hello .

I have a regex which works to fetch all content based on tags but not with id.
Here is wahat my regex is

```
**myHtml.match("<h2(.|\n)*?<\/h2>")**
```

But i am not sure how to regex with an particular id tag to match.

Comment: What about just using `document.querySelector( '#onlythisneedstobereturned' ).innerHTML` ? Why do you need to parse the HTML as a string?

Comment: Is this code running in a browser or NodeJS? If in a browser then you could use the DOM for this instead. If it's a string you can create a DOMFragment from it and use `querySelector`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379731/regular-expression-to-extract-content-from-a-div-whose-id-starts-with-a-specifc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/746736

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need Regex here, use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) like :

```js
const htmlStr = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<h2 id="onlythisneedstobereturned"> hello </h2>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlStr, "application/xml");

const content = doc.querySelector('#onlythisneedstobereturned').innerHTML;

console.log(content);
```